# Remove a block of text from a file

Tags: python-3.x

I have searched this and tried to adapt some answers to my problem.

The text format I'm trying to remove is like this:

```
text
text 
            rectangle 
           (
                gab "BACKGROUND" 
                set("can be different") 
                origin(can be different) 
                width(can be different)
                height(can be different)
            )
text
text
```

I'm trying to remove the rectangle and everything in between the brackets including the brackets.
These rectangles appear a few times in the file.

So far I have the following:

```
def removeBlock(): 

for somefile in os.listdir(source_folder):
    if (somefile.startswith(('DTSPSM_')) and somefile.endswith(('.ddl'.lower()))):
        with open(os.path.join(source_folder, somefile), 'r') as file :

            lines = file.read()
            lines.strip()
            for lines in file:
                blockstart = lines.index('rectangle')         
                del(lines[blockstart:blockstart+7])               
                open(os.path.join(source_folder, somefile), 'w+').writelines(lines)
```

But it doesn't remove the rectangle lines, can someone help please?

My current (working code) code looks like this now:

```
import shutil
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path
import typing

source_folder = r'C:\Test'
test_file = r'C:Test\DTSPSM_01.ddl'

def parseFile(src_file: typing.Union[Path, str], simulation: bool=False):
    print(src_file)
    if isinstance(src_file, str):
        src_file = Path(src_file)
    with src_file.open('r') as input_file:
        counter = 0
        for line in input_file:
            if line.strip() =='rectangle':
                counter = 7
                print(f'-{counter}-removing: {line}')
                continue
            elif counter > 0:
                counter -= 1
                print(f'-{counter}-removing: {line}')
                continue
            else:
                yield line

def clean_file(src_file:typing.Union[Path, str], simulation: bool=False):
    if isinstance(src_file, str):
        src_file = Path(src_file)
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
        temp_filename = f'{tmpdirname}/{src_file.name}.txt'
        with open(temp_filename, 'w') as temp_file:
            for line in parseFile(src_file, simulation=simulation):
                temp_file.write(line)
        if not simulation:
            shutil.copy(temp_filename, src_file)

def main():

    for src_file in Path(source_folder).glob("DTSPSM_*.ddl"):
        print(f'***{src_file}***\n')
        clean_file(src_file)


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent writing and reading from the same file you can use a temporary file, and then copy this to replace the original file. This way you also don't need to worry about what happens when something interrupts the process

## Parsing a single file:

```
def parse_file(src_file: typing.Union[Path, str], simulation: bool=False):
    if isinstance(src_file, str):
        src_file = Path(src_file)
    with src_file.open('r') as input_file:
        counter = 0
        for line in input_file:
            if line.strip() =='rectangle':
                counter = 7
                print(f'-{counter}-removing: {line}')
                if simulation:
                    yield line
                continue
            elif counter > 0:
                counter -= 1
                print(f'-{counter}-removing: {line}')
                if simulation:
                    yield line
                continue
            else:
                yield line
```

This can be easily expanded where you feed a dict of words and linenumbers to ignore as extra argument. I've added a `simulation` argument so you can do a dry run without altering anything

This can be easily tested by passing a file you know:

```
test_file = "DTSPSM_0.dll"
for line in parse_file(test_file):
    print(line)
```

> ```
> text1
> text2 
> -7-removing:             rectangle 
> -6-removing:            (
> -5-removing:                 gab "BACKGROUND" 
> -4-removing:                 set("can be different") 
> -3-removing:                 origin(can be different) 
> -2-removing:                 width(can be different)
> -1-removing:                 height(can be different)
> -0-removing:             )
> text3
> text4
> ```

```
def clean_file(src_file:typing.Union[Path, str], simulation: bool=False):
    if isinstance(src_file, str):
        src_file = Path(src_file)
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
        temp_filename = f'{tmpdirname}/{src_file.name}.txt'
        with open(temp_filename, 'w') as temp_file:
            for line in parse_file(src_file, simulation=simulation):
                temp_file.write(line)
        if not simulation:
            shutil.copy(temp_filename, src_file)
```

This writes the lines of the parsed file to a file in a temporary directory, and when finished copies this temporary file to overwrite the original file

This can be easily tested with 1 file too

## Finding the files:

`pathlib.Path.glob` is easier than `os.listdir`

```
for src_file in Path(sourcedir).glob("DTSPSM_*.dll"):
    print(f'***{src_file}***\n')
    clean_file(src_file, simulation=True)
```

This can be easily tested seperately by commenting the last line

Comment: I tried this but it's still not removing the code, although I did have to make some edits as I couldn't get the pathlib.Path.glob to work so I ended up using:
`for src_file in os.listdir(source_folder): if (src_file.startswith(('DTSPSM_')) src_file.endswith(('.ddl'.lower()))): print(f'***{src_file}***\n')`

Comment: I also had to use: 
`with open(os.path.join(source_folder, file),'r') as input_file:` 
In the function as I kept getting "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'open'

Comment: try: `for src_file in Path(source_folder).glob("DTSPSM_*.dll"):
        print(f'***{src_file}***\n')` to see whether it finds the correct files

Comment: It's not working properly yet, although I am implementing with a `main():` 
I have the replacing part in the main(): and the parser just as a normal function.
I also couldn't get the `typing`.Union[Path, str]` it was not recognizing `typing'.
Anyway at the moment the new file only outputs 360 lines out of 3000ish where the rectangle blocks when removed should only account for 100 lines.
I'm not sure why this is the case, do you have any other ideas?
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: the `typing` that is type hint information to let the IDE help you find errors

Comment: I have it working now!!
Thanks so much for the patience and help.